# Sql,how to get these results?

Tags: sql, sql-like

Here is the table structure and output i need to need please provided some suggestion.

```
| requestid | requeststatus |         note             | lasted updated date |
|     2123  |     open      | copy from requestid 1234 | 2018/8/19           |
|     2124  |    follow up  | copy from requestid 3456 | 2018/8/20           |
```

how to write a function to get result of requestid which is in the note. 
for example i need to get 1234(which is request id from there user information is copy) as output.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: You should include your environment information while asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
select distinct  requestid, reverse(LEFT(REVERSE(Note),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Note)))) as Cloneformid ,note,CreatedDate,ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER by CreatedDate desc) as rn 
from table 
where   Note like 'cloned from request Id %' 
)
select RequestID, cast(Cloneformid  as int) as Cloneformid
from cte
where   rn =1 and  isnumeric(Cloneformid) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle, use:

```
select substr(note, -4) from table where 1;
```

If you are using MS SQL,

```
select right(note, 4) from table where 1;
```

If you are using MySQL,

```
select substr(note, char_length(note) - 3, 4) from table where 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `exists` and subquery `like`

```
SELECT * 
FROM T t1
WHERE exists (
     SELECT 1 
     FROM T tt
     WHERE tt.note like '%' + t1.requestid  + '%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the request always the last four characters?

If so, this will work in most databases:

```
select t.*, right(note, 4)
from t;
```